# Rails 4 fields_for update - default selection not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, fields-for

I am working on Rails 4 project now, and I have `select` in `field_for` form for update.

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient_fields|%>
 <%= ingredient_fields.text_area :name %>
 <%= ingredient_fields.select :price do %>
   <%= options_for_select([['cheap', 1], ['expensive', 2]], :price) %>
 <% end %>
 <%= link_to_remove_fields 'Remove this ingredient', f %>
<% end %>
```

But this update form does not reflect the `:price` attribute which `ingredient` object already has.

( For example, even if I have an ingredient object with `expensive` `:price` attribute, the select input for that object does not select `expensive` by default. )

How can I set the default for `select` in `fields_for` when updating?

Comment: Does `ingredient_fields.select :price, [['cheap', 1], ['expensive', 2]]` work without the block? Or `options_for_select([['cheap', 1], ['expensive', 2]], your_object_here.price)` should do it. Right now you are just passing a symbol `:price` as the selected value and this does not exist in the "container"

Comment: Yes the first suggestion worked for me! thank you! :)  (I could not try the second one since I do not have specific ingredient object I can access, because I am using fields_for.)